# Wordcloud per topic for quanteda textmodel_lda in R

Tags: text-mining, lda, topic-modeling, quanteda, wordcloud2

Is there any possibility to extract wordclouds for each topic from quanteda textmodels_lda  in R?

All approaches I tried failed as I am not able to extract terms, topics and frequency from the model an put it into a wordcloud.

Thank you very much!